# Simulate Clicking or Pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with one of my javascripts. Im using this code `$('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group').change('select#groupid');` to select from a drop down menu, but unless i click it, it doesnt change some variables and values on the page. How can i simulate clicking it or anything? Someone said `change()` but it didnt work using `$('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group').change();` either.

Any ideas? I would assume simulating a click or enter would work if thats possible?

This is what i see for change if anthing [image]

Comment: What you suspect how someone changes a select? (I always click or use enter to select something in a select box)

Comment: Im trying to automate a site with javascript. So when i choose the dropdown it doesnt confirm until i click it.

Comment: How is the `change` event handler bound to that `<select>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `.trigger('change')`

```
$('select[name="groupid"]').val('Crew Group').trigger('change');
```

Comment: @sonicboom Minified code is absolutely useless; we need it in a readable format.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist where do you recommend i host it? its pretty long

Comment: @sonicboom I imagine not *all* of it is relevant to this question, so the first thing is to cut it down to the parts of the code that actually *are* relevant. Then edit those into this question.

Comment: Let me see if i can find some of it. I believe this may be relevent

Comment: Anything in there helpful?